# C# SerialDataReceivedEventHandler triggered without serialport connected

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm implementing a GUI in order to transmit a command to a device and to recive feedback from it.  Even if I have no device connected on the serial port, when I transmit data I get back the same data I've sent.  That is,  the `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler` is activated.

These are the `serialPort.write()` commands I use

```
 ......
 serialPort1.Write("on\r");
 Thread.Sleep(500);
 serialPort1.Write("GL\r");
 Thread.Sleep(500);
 serialPort1.Write("of\r"); 
 ......
```

And this is the associated EventHandler

```
this.serialPort1.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this.serialPort1_DataReceived);
```

After each write, `serialPort1_DataReceived` is activated and with a                `serialPort1.ReadLine()`
I get the same data I have written to the serial port.

How is possible?  It is like I'm sending data to myself.  My PC has no device connected. 
When I connect the serial port to the device,  I get back the real answer.

Comment: Most obvious reason is that you used the wrong port number and are actually talking to a modem.  It also has an electrical explanation, RS-232 is an unterminated bus with makes it liable to cross-talk between the wires when the cable is not plugged-in.  The higher the baudrate, the more likely that this will happen.  It is just not a very useful test, be sure to use the screws on the connector so it cannot fall out.